# Swiper: slideTo(".slide-classname")

Tags: jquery, magento, swiper.js

Does Swiper (http://www.idangero.us/swiper) provide an event to slide to a slide with a specific class? There is an event slideTo(index) but I need something like slideTo(".slide-classname").

This is what I am trying to do - maybe a different approach is possible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function(){
      $j("#attribute529").change(function() { 
        var optionValue = $j(this).val();
        var optionValueText = $j.trim($j('#attribute529 :selected').text());
        if( ! optionValue ){ 
          galleryTop.slideTo(0);
        } else {
          galleryTop.slideTo(".product-image_" + optionValueText);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a solution below, here I've created a function `getSlideIndexByClass` which will return the index of an element in slider by it's class name, and then I just call the `slideTo` function with that index value.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true
});

swiper.slideTo(getSlideIndexByClass('my-class'));

function getSlideIndexByClass(className) {
  var index = 0;
  $.each($('.swiper-wrapper').children(), function(i, item) {
    if ($(item).hasClass(className)) {
      index = i;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return index;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide my-class">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but where would I add this function? i tried adding it to my swiper js code (which is located in a differnet template file) and also tried adding it directly to my code shown above but I can not get it to work.

Comment: add the `getSlideIndexByClass` function on the same script tag you've mentioned in your question and then call `galleryTop.slideTo(getSlideIndexByClass(".product-image_" + optionValueText));` instead of `galleryTop.slideTo(".product-image_" + optionValueText);`

Comment: So the problem is that my swiper script and the script I posted are located in two different template files.
Using your code within my media.phtml (where the swiper is located) will work, so I have accepted your answer.
As I can't put my script into media.phtml, I will have to figure out how to make this work across seperate template files to allow for image switch on option select.

Comment: then create a js file containing getSlideIndexByClass function and place that file in a top level directory, from where all files can access it.